# How do I check if an array is in ascending order in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, any

suppose that I have the following NumPy array:

```
x = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5])
```

I'd like to check if the numbers are in ascending order, i.e., if exists a number larger than the number before, it should warn me. I believe that I can do it with the `any` syntax, but I'm not sure how. For instance, I've been trying:

```
if any(x[i] < x[i-1] for i in range(len(x))):
    print('Warning!')
```

But it's not working properly. It should activate the warning in arrays like `[0,2,1,3,4,5]`, and so on. Could someone please help me fix this issue? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Unfortunately `"But it's not working properly"` is not a proper description of the fault. What symptoms do you see?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`np.diff`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) and check if it is all positive.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5])
>>> np.diff(arr)
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
>>> (np.diff(arr) >= 0).all()
True
```

Or

```
>>> arr = np.array([0,2,1,3,4,5])
>>> np.diff(arr)
array([ 2, -1,  2,  1,  1])
>>> (np.diff(arr) >= 0).all()
False
```

Note, you could use `any`/`all` here as well, but you should try to use numpy operations on numpy arrays. But just for clarification, you basically wanted `all(arr[i] <= arr[i+1] for i in range(len(arr) -1))`.

And note, I'm expressing things in terms of "all", but you can use "any" equivalently:

```
(np.diff(arr) < 0).any()
```

And of course, `any(arr[i] > arr[i+1] for i in range(len(arr) -1))`.

Finally, you must decide how to treat the case of no change, i.e. when the difference between subsequent elements is 0. Since you used the terminology "ascending order", typically, `[1, 1, 2, 3]` i considered in ascending order so I've used that convention above (edited since originally posted))

Answer (score 0):

As has already been said, you should use numpy operations on numpy arrays. However, in this trivial case you could just do this:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([0,1,2,3,6,5])

for i in range(len(x)-1):
    if x[i] > x[i+1]:
        print('Not sorted')
        break
else:
    print('Sorted')
```